# HTML5 video in Internet Explorer renders colors incorrectly

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, h.264, video-encoding

I have a video (mp4/h264) that I am implementing on a page using the -tag. Its a video of a man talking with a white background. The video plays on all supported browsers. However, on IE something odd happens to the color of the film.

Here is a screenshot: http://bayimg.com/EAahEaaGB

As you can see IE shows the video in some kind of tinted color. This is a big problem as I need the background of the video to be white.

The code used to embed the movie:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <video id="video1">
                    <source src="video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've done a fair bit of googling and seen a few other ppl having similar issues but found no solutions. One of the more promising things i found was ticket over at microsoft: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/797470/rec709-colour-space-in-h264-videos-give-wrong-results-in-html5-player-in-ie10

It is closed and marked working as intended, but in it they talk about SPS and colour spaces. I dont really understand such things and how I am supposed to implement them.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and solved it? Is there something in the encoding process of the video that i have to change?

Comment: Have you tried giving the `html`/`body` tags an explicit background? Some older browsers used to use grey as the default.

Comment: yes i have. it does not affect the video appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research we found that the problem only occured on windows machines using radeons Catalyst  Control Center. It seems that there are a bunch of settings, image enhancements and such, that affect the colors of the video.

All in all, we found no way of correcting the problem through html/css/js or encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this post, and thought I would add what we have found. The problem here is with Hardware Acceleration, which is on by default. Turn off hardware acceleration (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2528233) and the video will be white again.

I do not know how to fix this though.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in IE and found that this setting on integrated intel graphics will cause video color issues.

[image: Intel HD Graphics Control Panel]